# Receiving error: "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list"

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to set up a piece of software that runs on Python & Django. The instructions say to use the following command to generate an SQL database:

`python manage.py migrate`

However, when I do this, I receive the following error:

> python : Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> + python manage.py migrate
>
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (most recent call last)::String)
>           [], RemoteException
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> File "manage.py", line 10, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 353, in 
>   execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 302, in 
>   execute
>       settings.INSTALLED_APPS
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py", line 55, in **getattr**
>       self._setup(name)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
>       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py", line 99, in **init**
>       mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>
> File "F:\directory\settings.py", line 117, in 
>       TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
>
> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

This seems to indicate that the problem is in line 116 of the 'settings.py' file, which I have below:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
from django.conf import global_settings

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'game',
    'admin_views',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cagweb.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'game/templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cagweb.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
#LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'

LOCALE_PATHS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
)
```

Could someone help me understand how to fix this problem?

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I am using Windows 7, Python 2.7, and Powershell to try to run this software.

Thank you in advance! If I have left any information out, please let me know and I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` is an empty tuple whereas `[]` represents an empty list.

Since `global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` is a `list` type, you should only concatenate that to another list:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + []
```

Comment: Dear @ozgur - thank you very much! This seems to have worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Example 1

```
>>> type(())
<type 'tuple'>
```

Example 2

```
>>> [1,2,3] + ()
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

On the last line of your example code, you're adding `()`, which is , by the first example 1, the literal for an empty tuple. By your error and example 2, i can assume that `global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` is a list, and you are trying to "list + tuple", which is incompatible to `__add__` and raises that exception.

Try changing the last line to:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
```

or, if by some unknown reason, you really need to add something...

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + []
```

Comment: Dear @Diogo Martin - thank you! This seems to have worked!

Comment: Glad to help, @Yasha